# total price doesn't display the value

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

```
List cart =[];
 double totalPrice = 0.0;

   //here is i retrieve cart item from database to calculate
 Future getData() async {
   final CollectionReference reference =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cart');
   reference.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email).collection('items').get().then((ds) {
     ds.docs.forEach((data) {
       /*var temp = {
         'image': data['image'],
         'name': data['name'],
         'category': data['category'],
         'price': data['price'],
       };*/

      
       setState(() {
         cart.add(data['price']);
         double e = double.parse(data['price']);
         totalPrice = totalPrice + e;
       });

       print(totalPrice.toStringAsFixed(2));
     });
   });
 }

  double getTotalPrice() {  // calculate of my total price
   double totPrice = 0.00;
   for(int i=0; i<cart.length; i++){
     String price = cart[i];
     double p = double.parse(price);
     totPrice = totPrice + p;

   }
   return totPrice;
 }

 @override
 void initState() {
   // TODO: implement initState
   super.initState();
   getData();
   getTotalPrice();
 }

 Future<void> initPayment({required String email, required double amount, required BuildContext context}) async {
   double newAmount = amount * 100;
   try {

     // create a payment intent on the server
     final response = await http.post(
         Uri.parse('https://us-central1-market-3387e.cloudfunctions.net/stripePaymentIntentRequest'),
         body: {
           'email': email,
           'amount': newAmount.toString(),
           'payment_method_types[]': "card",
         });

 double roundDouble(double value, int places){
   num mod = pow(10.0, places);
   return ((value * mod).round().toDouble() / mod);
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     bottomNavigationBar: Container(
       child: ElevatedButton(
         child: Text('Payment', style: GoogleFonts.hammersmithOne(
    
           // i can't display total price value here at amount:
         onPressed: () async {
           double h = roundDouble(totalPrice, 2);
           await initPayment(amount: h, context: context, email: 'test@gmail.com');
         },
       ),
     ),
```

I do not know why but i already calculate the total price at getTotalPrice() function, but when i declare var h at the amount, it doesn't display the value cause i think i already did true. can someone show me how it supposed to be the calculation because i already declare in the stripe function.

var h is where i declare my calculation of total price but i doesn't display the value it doesn't working. When i route from shopping cart to payment page , the total price doesn't retrieve and display the value. I already retrieve data from my database from "cart" collection